# How to stop film roll in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have been searching on google how to stop a FILMROLL if a button is clicked but I couldn't find anything. I've been scrolling on their guide but there is no such thing as destroy or stopping of slider. Here is the  [plugin](https://github.com/straydogstudio/film_roll) and the guide. And, below are my codes:

```
<script>
 $(function() {  
    var slideimage = new FilmRoll({ 
        container: '#slide_images', 
        height: 'auto',
        pager : false,
        scroll : true,
        start_index : 2
    });
    $('button').click(function(){
       //stop the slider
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="slide_images"> 
  <div data-caption="Headset" data-id="0"><a href="#"><img src="images/headset.jpg"></a></div> 
  <div data-caption="drum"  data-id="1"><a href="#"><img src="images/drum.jpeg"></a></div> 
  <div data-caption="bass"  data-id="2"><a href="#"><img src="images/bass.jpeg"></a></div>  
  <div data-caption="guitar" data-id="3"><a href="#"><img src="images/guitar.jpeg"></a></div>  
</div> 
<button>Stop</button>
```

Also, after stopping the button, I want also this to resume to slide.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the best I could do. It requires that you set the `hover` option to false, otherwise hovering over the carousel will make it start to scroll again. If you want to carousel to start scrolling again after hovering or clicking an arrow then you can remove the `hover` option or set it to `true`.

Not very pretty but it's about the best you are going to get with the way it is built. Unfortunately there isn't really anyway to "re-configure" the carousel. Might want to check out something like slickjs (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) which I use all the time and has a lot more features/options. See if that might work for you.

Here is the code below that I came up with. Seemed to work in Chrome/Mac but did not do any extensive testing.

```js
  $(function() {  
    var slideimage = new FilmRoll({ 
        container: '#slide-images', 
        height: 'auto',
        pager : false,
        scroll : true,
        hover: false,
        start_index : 2
    });
    
    $('button').click(function(){
       //stop the slider
      slideimage.clearScroll();
    });
  });
```

```css
#slide-images > div {
  background: black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://straydogstudio.github.io/film_roll/js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://straydogstudio.github.io/film_roll/js/jquery.film_roll.min.js"></script>

<div id="slide-images">
  <div data-caption="Headset" data-id="0">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/headset.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <div data-caption="drum" data-id="1">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/drum.jpeg"></a>
  </div>
  <div data-caption="bass" data-id="2">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/bass.jpeg"></a>
  </div>
  <div data-caption="guitar" data-id="3">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/guitar.jpeg"></a>
  </div>
</div>

<button>Stop</button>
```

Comment: **slideimage.clearScroll();** thanks @creativekinetix

Comment: My pleasure, happy to help. :)